# How do I transform a single column list to item matrix in R?

Tags: r, transformation, etl

I currently have data that is in the following format (note, this is 1 column, 4 row matrix):

```
aa|bb  
bb|cc|ee|ee  
cc  
cc|ee
```

and I want it displayed so that the column names are: aa, bb, cc, dd, and ee.  And I want there to be 4 row such that each row counts the number of times each string was present in the matching row above.

ie)

```
aa bb cc dd ee  
 1  1  0  0  0  
 0  1  1  0  2  
 0  0  1  0  0   
 0  0  1  0  1
```

Does anyone know how to do this in R? I would post my attempt, but it is just getting ugly and complicated.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I rolled back your change to the title that included [Solved]; the way this is indicated on Stack Overflow is to accept (select the check mark) of the best/right answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: @Brian -- Thanks for the edits, I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
# (You'll use as.vector() on your matrix to get the vector x.)
x <- c("aa|bb", "bb|cc|ee|ee", "cc", "cc|ee") 

levs <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee")
ll <- strsplit(x, "\\|")
t(sapply(ll, function(X) table(c(levs, X)))) - 1
#      aa bb cc dd ee
# [1,]  1  1  0  0  0
# [2,]  0  1  1  0  2
# [3,]  0  0  1  0  0
# [4,]  0  0  1  0  1
```

This may clarify (at least a bit) what that final line of code does:

```
table(c(levs, c("dd", "cc", "cc", "cc"))) - 1
# 
# aa bb cc dd ee 
#  0  0  3  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.  I guess I need more practice with the infinitely useful 'apply' function.

Comment: @Indy -- Glad I could help. Instead of marking this solved by putting "[Solved]" in its title, you can "Accept" my answer by clicking the check mark to its left. Cheers.